# Finding Member of First ArrayList with Highest Value in Second ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have an `ArrayList` of objects with two parameters `(name, value)`. I also have an `ArrayList` of a different type of objects with two other parameters `(value, suit)`. Each user corresponds (by index of 0-3) to the object in the second list with the same index.

I need to find the user who's value is the highest in the SECOND list.

How can I do this concisely? I feel like I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: post some code. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your name-value tuple type is `NameValue`, and assuming your other tuple type is `ValueSuit` you might do something like,

```
List<NameValue> firstList;
List<ValueSuit> secondList;
// ... firstList and secondList initialized ...
```

First, get the maximum value in the second list.

```
int maxValue = secondList.get(0).getValue();
for (ValueSuit vs : secondList) {
  maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, vs.getValue());
}
```

Then find the corresponding `NameValue`

```
NameValue out = null;
for (NameValue nv : firstList) {
  if (nv.getValue() == maxValue) {
    out = nv;
  }
}
System.out.println(out);
```